# Android playing sound on button click

Tags: android, media-player

I'm trying to  play multiple times two different .wav files on button click.
I want to play sound1 then sound2 then sound1 and so on..
here is fragment of code.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_box);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Box.this, R.drawable.sound1);
        mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(Box.this, R.drawable.sound2);
        handler = new Handler();

        sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                rounds = new Integer(et.getText().toString());
                for(int j = 0; j < rounds; j ++)
                {
                    f();
                    g();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void f()
    {
        cdt1 =  new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000)
        {
             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
             {

             }
             public void onFinish() 
             {   
                 mp.setLooping(true);
                 mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                 mp.start();
             }}.start();

    }
    public void g()
    {
        cdt =  new CountDownTimer(7000, 1000)
        {
             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
             {

             }
             public void onFinish() 
             {   
                 mp2.setLooping(true);
                 mp2.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                 mp2.start();
             }}.start();     
    }
```

Shall i reset them every time i play a sound ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there a question?!?

Comment: sound doesn't play in right order.
question at the end.

Comment: from what i see here. you are calling f and have a 5sec countdown until you start sound1. simultaneously you are starting g with a 7sec countdown for starting sound2?

Comment: I want to play sound1 after 5 sec when activity created then play sound2 after sound1 played and so on..

Comment: if so, you need some different kind of handling for the sounds. how about a detection of when the sounds are finished, so you can re-start them right on time.

Comment: 've tried to add onCompletion listener after each sound have been played and then stop -> prepare mediaplayer to play again, but the result is same

Answer (score 0):

you can check the mediaplayer if its still playing with something like:

```
if (mp.isPlaying()) {
    //do nothing
} else {
    //start new sound
}
```

Comment: Is this the right order:
Started -> Completed -> Stopped -> Prepared -> Started .. ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram